# Как в js из массива объектов получить значения по ключу?

Tags: javascript

Имеется массив объектов следующего вида

```
[
    {same_field: 'some value'},
    {same_field: 'one more value'}
]
```

Мне необходимо нативно, без использования циклов(с ними я и сам могу), получить массив значений `same_field` объектов данного массива, что бы на выходе это выглядело следующим образом:

```
['some value', 'one more value']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В каком смысле без циклов? Без использования for? Если да, то вот так можно:

```js
result = array.map(x => x.same_field)
```

А если вы имеете ввиду совсем без циклов, то можно рекурсивно пойти список, но спрашивается, с какой целью?

Comment: Предложенный вами вариант подходит идеально. Спасибо, человечище!